# Is it possible to have a JDBC pool that route read-only queries to a slave sql server?

Tags: java, sql, spring, jdbc

I try to search if there are JDBC Pool that have this capabilities. I use DBDC but there are no mentions of this. We also use spring, perhaps spring could help to do that ?

I want to route write query to my master sql server and read only query to the slave.

Are there an existing JDBC Pool library with this capabilities ?

Comment: Why don't you simply define two pools and decide from which one you want to obtain a connection depending on what you want to do?

Comment: How would the pool know whether it's a read-only query or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We are achieving what you want to do , not with jdbc but with a load balancer .

We have a slave and a master server  DBs. We are working with web services and loadbalancer can know the requested function by parsing the Request. When its a read-only function , it directs to slave , when it involves any writing , directs to master server.

[nginx wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nginx)
[load balancing example with nginx](http://library.linode.com/web-servers/nginx/configuration/front-end-proxy-and-software-load-balancing)